# Using an item from a list as a new dictionary key

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

Example:

```
a = {}
b = "item"
c = ["key1","key2"]

a[c][0] = b
```

If it worked the way I wanted it to it would result in:

```
>>>a
{"key1": "item"}
```

But instead I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    a[c][0] = b
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Is there a standard way to do this directly or do I need to go through further variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the indexing *in* to the actual list object:

```
a[c[0]] = b
```

because you want `c[0]` to be the key, not `c` itself.

In your version, Python first evaluates `a[c]` then indexes the result of that to `[0]`.

Demo:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = "item"
>>> c = ["key1","key2"]
>>> a[c[0]] = b
>>> a
{'key1': 'item'}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

because you are trying to use a list as a dict key. And that's not possible. To use a list element as a key to a new dict you should specify which list element you want to use as such.

`a[c[0]] = b` if you want `a` to be `{"key1": "item"}`.